# Property assingment expected in React conditional return

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

how should I best structure a conditional block that depends on loggedIn status. I am getting an error here Parsing error, unexpected token. What am I doing wrong and is there a better way to do this?

```
return (
    {
        (loggedIn || localStorage["token"]) ?
            <Redirect to={} />
        : 
            <div className="section">
                You are not logged In
            </div>

    }
)
```

Comment: Remove the brackets (`{`) that you have wrapped inside the return statement.

Answer (score 1):

First, remove `{}`

Then, according to the javascript [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), Logical OR (`||`) has a higher priority than Conditional operator (`… ? … : …`)

```
5   Logical OR  left-to-right   … || …
4   Conditional right-to-left   … ? … : …
```

so you don't need `()` as well

---

```
return (
  loggedIn || localStorage["token"]
    ? <Redirect to={} />
    : <div className="section">
        You are not logged In
      </div>
)
```